# Get collection of filtered products (layered navigation)

Tags: layered-navigation, product-collection, layer

I am trying to get a collection of products according to filters applied in layered navigation.

I thought, that layer model's getProductCollection will do it for me, but as long as i see, it retrieves all products in the category without filters applied.

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')
            ->getProductCollection();
        throw new \Exception(print_r($productCollection->load()->getSelectSql(1),1));
```

How can i get what i need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this :

```
$productCollection= Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getProductCollection();
```